Why does my x64 Assembly program have a segmentation fault?
I've been testing different Syscalls recently in x64, so this program was supposed to allow me to append to the end of a file using lseek, everything before it works out, but for some reason at the end of the exit syscall after exit has been called, there's this random instruction that I didn't put in.
Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000401069 in exit ()
(gdb) si
0x000000000040106b in exit ()
(gdb) si
0x000000000040106e in exit ()
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x40106e <exit+5>:   syscall
(gdb) si
0x0000000000401070 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x401070:    add    %al,(%rax)
(gdb) disass/r exit
Dump of assembler code for function exit:
   0x0000000000401069 <+0>:     b0 3c                   mov    $0x3c,%al
   0x000000000040106b <+2>:     40 b7 00                mov    $0x0,%dil
   0x000000000040106e <+5>:     0f 05                   syscall
End of assembler dump.


This is the file itself
%include "fileio.s"
global _start

section .text
_start:
        openat -100, file, U_EXEC+UGO_RW, STDIN
        mov rdi, rax
        mov al, 0x8
        mov rsi, 00
        mov rdx, 0x2
        syscall
        fchmod rdi, UGO_RW
        write rdi, message, len
        syncfs rdi
        close rdi

exit:
        mov al, 0x3c
        mov dil, 0x0
        syscall

section .data
file:
        db "Payload.txt", 0
message:
        db "Ahoy Matey", 0xa
len equ $-message



I tried using xxd to find the instruction in the binary and remove it, but the instruction isn't in the binary, I tried reassembling the program, but it gets the same thing, I also noticed that this was happening to a couple of other programs that I made, so I'm thinking that it may not have to do with the programs that I'm making, but something wrong in the environment itself.

add %al, (%rax) is encoded as 00 00.  You're seeing zeroes being disassembled.  This issue is possibly that you move the syscall number into al, keeping the upper bits of eax as is, but they may be nonzero at that point.  Try to move the syscall number into eax to avoid this.

Probably the upper bits of RAX aren't zero after returning from close, whatever that macro does.  Only writing a 32-bit register zero-extends into the full reg, writing AL merges with the old value.  Use strace ./a.out to see that you're probably getting -ENOSYS instead of a call to exit.  Also, you can use set disassembly-flavor intel to get asm that's closer to NASM.

BTW, the close system call leaves EAX=0 on success, and in practice very likely sign-extended to 64-bit so generic syscall wrappers can detect error, in which case this code-golf hack  of using mov al, 60 would work.  If you're trying to save code size, xor edi, edi is the most compact way to zero RDI.  (The exit status is technically 32 bits, although most things can only retrieve the low 8 bits.)

@fuz Thank you so mcuh, it worked, I didn't realize that it wouldn't automatically clear the upper bits.
